# displaying answers to division problems in java

Tags: java, swing

I have a program that shows random math problems then the answers.

Anytime the problem is division the answer comes out to 0.

I think its because I need to use float instead of int to show the answer. Can someone show me hot to change my program to display the division problem answers correctly.

here is my program.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Driver extends MathProblems {

    MathProblems problems = new MathProblems();

    String s = "Welcome Students!";
    String b = "Start!";
    private JFrame f;
    private JPanel p;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JButton b1 = new JButton(b);

    JLabel jl = new JLabel(s);

    int i;

    public Driver () {      
        gui();  
    }

    public void gui() { 
        f = new JFrame("Flash Card Program");       
        p = new JPanel();   
        f.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2, 1 ) );
        f.add(jl);
        f.add(p);
        p.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2, 1 ) );
        p.add(b1);

        jl.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        // pack the frame for better cross platform support
        f.pack();
        // Make it visible
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(560,400); // default size is 0,0
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if(b1.getText().equals("Click For Answer"))
                {
                    jl.setText(problems.toString());
                    b = "Next Question";
                    b1.setText(b);
                }
                else
                {
                    problems.run();
                    jl.setText(problems.getQuestion());
                    b = "Click For Answer";
                    b1.setText(b);

                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
                new Driver();
           }
        });
    } // End main Method

} // End class Driver
```

MathProblems

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MathProblems {
     private static final int MAX_NUMBER = 10;
     private static final Random random = new Random();

     private int expected = 0;
     private String question = "";

     public void run() {
         final int a = random.nextInt(MAX_NUMBER);
         final int b = random.nextInt(MAX_NUMBER);

         final int type = random.nextInt(4);

         switch (type) {
             case 0: 
                 add(a, b);
                 break;
             case 1: 
                subtract(a, b);
                break;
             case 2:
                multiply(a, b);
                break;
             case 3:
                 divide(a, b);
                 break;
         }
     }

     private void add(final int a, final int b) {
         expected = a + b;

         askQuestion(a + " + " + b + " = ");
     }

     private void subtract(final int a, final int b) {
         expected = a - b;

         askQuestion(a + " - " + b + " = ");
     }

     private void multiply(final int a, final int b) {
         expected = a * b;

         askQuestion(a + " * " + b + " = ");
     }

     private void divide(final int a, final int b) {
         expected = a / b;

         askQuestion(a + " / " + b + " = ");
     }

     private  void askQuestion(final String question) {
         this.question = question;
     }  

     public String getQuestion() {
         return question;
     }

     public int getAnswer() {
         return expected;
   }

     @Override
     public String toString(){
     return Integer.toString(expected);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing integer calculation. That will result in `int`. It doesn't matter, in what data type you are storing the result.

For example

```
double d = 10/3;
```

result will be 3.0 not 3.3333333

you can solve it by making any one to float or double

```
double d = (float)10/3;
```

Comment: Would you mind showing me in my code how to do that?

Comment: Do some changes `private double expected = 0;` and `expected = (double)a / b;` in divide method.

Comment: ok so if i change that and now where im doing Integer.toString has error cause its a double now. Should I just change all the int to double? and when I do that do I still need to do int.toString? or is that a double toString equivalent?

Comment: Yes you have to change it to `Double.toString()` and Please try to do some experiment if you really want to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are diving two integers. Multiply either the numerator or the denominator by 1.0 and the problem should be fixed. In that case, you must also change the type of expected to be either float or double.

Comment: Look at this output `System.out.println(10/3*1.0);`.

Comment: @Braj: Well, you are doing it wrong. In that case, since both multiplication and division have the same priority, the evaluation first do the multiplication (results in an integer), and only then the division.

My answer is correct, but you have to interpret it right. You can multiply the denominator by 1.0, but in that case, you need to put it in parenthesis.

Check System.out.println(10/(3.0 * 1.0));

For the numerator, that is not required, as it would be evaluated first.